# How can I get valueprovider in asp.net core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, value-provider

In MVC5, I used to obtain a `ValueProvider` within a Controller Action like this:

```cs
public class ConfigurationsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var valueProvider = this.ValueProvider;
        var someValue = valueProvider.GetValue("someKey");
        return View();
    }
}
```

But it seems to be gone in Asp.NET Core 1.0. Is there a way to get the `ValueProvider` in the new version?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Curious, why are you trying to use the value provider explicitly here? I ask as there could be new support in ASP.NET Core 1.0 for which you might not even need to do this!

Comment: I need binding value from value provider to a model manually. Because I do not know model to binder before. Please explorer this code to undestand my target: http://csharppad.com/gist/5ab037c3a2112d2a0fb0a76b94cf6023

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `CompositeValueProvider` using `ControllerContext`.

```
var valueProvider = await CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ControllerContext);
```

> CompositeValueProvider represents 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IValueProvider whose values come
>   from a collection of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.IValueProviders.

Example

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction()
{
    var valueProvider = await CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ControllerContext);
    var someValue = valueProvider.GetValue("foo");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have checked the source code Mvc and found it same with your answer!